# Wordpress Add new media error

Tags: wordpress, permissions, media

I have recently uploaded my new site and edited the permissions to the folders, but returned all files permission and folders back to original state but now when i try to upload a picture to the media library i get this following message.

Error -1.jpg
The uploaded file could not be moved to wp-content/uploads/2014/09.

I now cant upload anything.

my public_html and folders are set to 755 and files to 644.

I have also tried to add a option_value to upload_path phpMyadmin which is currently empty, but this did not work.

would love some help

Answer (score 0):

Set a `755` to upload floder by the Fttp details or cpanel

Comment: Yes, I too tried this, this is not the issue.  As I recently discovered when moving to a GoDaddy dedicated server.  I had just moved the files to a new server, and the permissions on the uploads directory had not changed at all - they were still 755.  It turns out, they were running PHP as a Module in Apache, and it needed to be run as FastCGI.  This is exactly what the GoDaddy tech said to me, and after changing this, my uploads were working again.

@nitu, have you called your hosting company and asked about this?  Please let me know if this helps.  It was the answer for me.

Answer (score 0):

Please create a folder named `uploads` inside `wp-content` folder and set `755 permission` to it. This will solve the problem.

Comment: I already have an uploads folder that exists in the wp-content folder and the permissions are set to 755 =(

Answer (score 0):

Check with your hosting company and make sure that PHP is enabled as FastCGI rather than an Apache module

Comment: If this answer was helpful or you used it, can you please upvote it?  Thanks!